# Handling string conversion overflow, special case

Tags: c, string

```
for(end = i - 1, exp = 0, long_int = 0L; end >= start; end--, exp++)
{
    multiplier = pow(base, exp);
    sum = 0L;
    if(*(str + end) >= '0' && *(str + end) <= '9') 
        sum = (*(str + end) - '0') * multiplier;
    else if(*(str + end) >= 'A' && *(str + i) <= (base == BASE_MAX ? 'Z' : 'F')) 
        sum = (*(str + end) - 'A' + 10) * multiplier;
    else if(*(str + end) >= 'a' && *(str + i) <= (base == BASE_MAX ? 'z' : 'f'))
        sum = (*(str + end) - 'a' + 10) * multiplier;
    if(long_int >= LLONG_MAX - sum)
        break;
    else
        long_int += sum;
}
if(sign == POSITIVE && long_int > LONG_MAX)
{
    errno = ERANGE;
    return LONG_MAX;
}
else if(sign == NEGATIVE && sign * long_int < LONG_MIN)
{
    errno = ERANGE;
    return LONG_MIN;
}
else
    return (long int) sign * long_int;
```

I'm writting sample strtol implementation. The code works fine but there's a special case for which i'm getting wrong behaviour. For example let's take a string "F0000000000000000000000000000000F" if we try to convert it  we will have some small number at the beginning and very large at some later point of the conversion. The method i used does not cause overflow because long_int (that's final value to which we add subsequent converted characters of the string) is long long int and sum (that's the value which we will add to the long_int) is also long long int. The thing is I'm stopping the function at the point when summing this two numbers would overflow but in the presented case the long_int has small value to which i cannot add the sum to not cause overflow. the long_int doesn't meet the requirement of the both if statements so the conversion is performed and the final result is the small value converted at the beginning. Could you give me any tips ho to solve it?

Edit:
To give you better overview i post the example of first the result of standard gcc function and then mine

```
0xFF000000000000000000F0 in base 0 is 7FFFFFFF
strtol: Numerical result out of range
End pointer points to ""

0xFF000000000000000000F0 in base 0 is F0
strtol: Success
End pointer points to ""
```

Edit2:
Variable declarations

```
#define MAX_BASE 36
..............................................................
..............................................................
long long int long_int, sum, multiplier;
int i, exp;

//base is int constant passed to a function, sign is 1 or -1 depending on a string
```

Comment: 1) show code variable declarations.  2) Check for potential overflow _before_ the `*` or `+` operation, not afterward.  E.g. After converting `char` to digit, `int limit = LONG_MAX/base; if (sum > limit || ((sum == limit) && (digit > LONG_MAX%base))) Handle_Overflow();  else sum = sum * base + digit;`

Comment: updated with variable declarations. Could you explain your method more. I think i saw something similar but i don't think i really understand it.

Comment: Still have not declare missing variables: assuming `int end; int start;  int  end; int i; int base; const char * str; int sign;
#define BASE_MAX 36 #define POSITIVE ('+') #define NEGATIVE ('-')`

Comment: everything right, i is just index, and in start i store the beginning of the correct string, in the end i store the end index of the correct part of the string. sign is -1 (NEGATIVE) or 1(POSITIVE) the rest is the same as for normal strtol implementation long int strtol(const char *str, char **endptr, int base);

Comment: 1) added thought: Instead of accumulating the answer in the range 0 to INT_MAX, use the range 0 to INT_MIN. 2) `while (isalnum(*(str + end))) { int digit = foo(*(str + end)); if (digit >= base) break; if ((y <= limit) && ((y < limit) || (digit >= -(INT_MIN % base)))) {    y = INT_MIN; overflow = 1; } else { y *= base; y -= digit; } end++;` After the loop `if (sign != '-') { if (y < -INT_MAX) { overflow = true; } if (overflow) { y = INT_MAX; } else y = -y; } if (overflow) { errno = ERANGE; }`  GTG - sorry.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. When you will return could you explain me this second method more. I'd like to test it also but i don't understand it. Oh and also i think you meant LONG_MAX and LONG_MIN instead of INT_MAX etc.

Comment: Notice `y -= digit;`.  Rather than accumulate the answer as a positive number, accumulate the answer as a negative number.  0 to LONG_MIN is typically a wider range of numbers than 0 to LONG_MAX.  Wider by 1.  After accumulating the result, handle the case when the number if positive.

Comment: Solved i changed it a little bit. Instead of going from the beginning to the end i started accumulating number by calculating i's value as value = value * base + char and also changed the overflow check to check if value is >= (LONG_MAX - char) / base (that's for positive numbers) (value is int_long in my code and sum corresponds to char). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Good you are making a good solution. BTW: check `value > (LONG_MAX - char) / base`  `> vs. >=`.

Comment: yes i changed it to check only > (LONG_MAX - char) / base because it caused error on 32-bit machine. In case it's equal to LONG_MAX but we stop there we are not overflowing so we shouldn't set overflow to be true. Now it works perfectly on both x86 and x64 architecture. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved i changed it a little bit. Instead of going from the beginning to the end i started accumulating number by calculating i's value as value = value * base + char and also changed the overflow check to check if value is >= (LONG_MAX - char) / base (that's for positive numbers) (value is int_long in my code and sum corresponds to char). –  user3119781

i changed it to check only > (LONG_MAX - char) / base because it caused error on 32-bit machine. In case it's equal to LONG_MAX but we stop there we are not overflowing so we shouldn't set overflow to be true. Now it works perfectly on both x86 and x64 architecture. –  user3119781